# Can we join multiple stored procedure together?

Tags: mysql, laravel, stored-procedures

is there any stored procedure joined example can show?

Is it possible to join multiple stored procedure together ?

Comment: Join - no (not even sure what you mean by this) but you can call another procedure within a procedure (carefully avoiding loops). Can you explain the problem for which you think joining multiple SPs is a solution?

Comment: like i have SP A using select then SP B is for delete

Comment: This sounds like as if you needed a subquery, not different stored procedures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to join multiple stored procedures in mysql, since stored procedures do not have a defined return value and mysql does not have a table data type anyway.

You can write multiple stored proedures to use the same temporary table to interact with each other or you can call a stored procedure within another one with different parameters.